# Hibernate 3 XML MAPPING

Tags: java, hibernate3

I need to have an id starting with '10001'. How do I set an initial value for an auto increment primary key in mapping file?

Comment: Is it new feature in hibernate ??In previous versions there is no such facility and **not possible**.In other words,It depends on underlying database.